# Empty stdin between fgets calls

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

i have a code where i want 2 users input of 20 char max.
I want to only keep 20. My problem is that after the 1st input, if user entered more than 20 char, those chars are still in stdin so it will be read by the next fgets.

```
  char *pseudo = malloc(21);
  fgets(pseudo,21,stdin);
  strtok(pseudo,"\n");

  char * tube = malloc(21);
  fgets(tube,21,stdin);
  strtok(tube,"\n");
```

I found the following solution to empty stdin between 2 fgets calls, it works but it blocks between the 2 calls : i have to enter something to get asked the 2nd input.

```
int c = 0;
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

- Your loop logic is broken.
- Your should only execute the *fixed* loop if you detect your input line did not end with a newline, which is not being done at all.

So something like this trivial example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *pseudo = malloc(21);
    if (fgets(pseudo,21,stdin))
    {
        char *cr = strrchr(pseudo, '\n');
        if (cr == NULL)
        {
            int c;
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        else
        {
            *cr = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *pseudo = 0;
    }

    char * tube = malloc(21);
    if (fgets(tube,21,stdin))
    {
        char *cr = strrchr(tube, '\n');
        if (cr == NULL)
        {
            int c;
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        else
        {
            *cr = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *tube = 0;
    }

    printf("%s : %s\n", pseudo, tube);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
01234567890123456789012345
0123456789012345678
```

**Output**

```
01234567890123456789 : 0123456789012345678
```

Obviously you could refactor this to put all that duplicate code in a well-crafted function or two, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Certainly `strrchr(pseudo, '\n');` would always provide the same result as `strchr(pseudo, '\n');` after a `fgets()`.   Do you suspect better performance `strrchr()`?  I suppose there could be.

Comment: Since fgets add '\n' at the end of the input, finding a '\n' with strrrchr doesn't always mean that we read all character, does it ?

Comment: @chux  Honestly I'm with you in doubting it makes a difference. It is *feasible* a scasb under rep could be faster (akin to `strlen` + backoff one slot and load) compared to a forward hunt for a non-zero value, but I honestly have never taken the time to count the clock cycles. I usually use `strrchr` when explaining a question like this because it's easier for beginners to understand searching from the end of the string backwards. If it did make a performance difference, I'd be surprised.

Comment: @StuYYY Who told you `fgets` "adds `'\n'` to the end of input" ? It doesn't. It *keeps* it if it is present within the input stream (consuming it from said-same in the process) and space is available in the target buffer. It doesn't "add" it out of thin air. See [the documentation of `fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and read it carefully.

Comment: Indeed i misunderstood fgets doc. It work perfectly , thanks a lot !

Comment: @StuYYY No worries. Bookmark that site. it is honestly the best C and C++ language and library site you're apt to find, and is very well maintained. Best of luck.